# codeigniter uploading issues

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

i know this repeated question here , but i did not get meaning i can not understand. before i was uploaded the file using codeigniter format all are working fine. but the following code is give this error `Message: Undefined index: file_name`

my html code

```
   <?php echo form_open('fileuplod/setflag') ;?>        
            <input type="text" name="tagname" class="tagname" id="tagname" placeholder="Flag Name"> <br/>
            <input type="file" name="file_name" class="flagimg" id="flagimg">
            <input type="submit" name="flagsubmit"  value="set">
                      </div>                        
                    <?php 
                echo form_close(); ?>
```

and my php upload code

```
if($_FILES['file_name']['name'] != "")
          {
            $config['upload_path'] ='images/flag';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png'; 
            $config['overwrite'] = false;  
            $ext =pathinfo($_FILES['file_name']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $config['file_name']= $ext; 
             $imgname = $config['file_name'];     

             $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);    
            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file_name'))
                {
                $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $data= array('error'=>$error,);
                $this->load->view('error',$data);
                return false;
                }
          }
```

i can not identify why this error arise. please help anyone

Comment: Are you using `form_open_multipart()` or not?

Comment: oh shit how can i forget this. your absolute correct nioly saha. i was forget to add multipart in my code. thanks to you

Answer (score 2):

Use `form_open_multipart()` in your form declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Add this or replace your form_open()

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
```

or

```
<form method="post" action="<?=site_url("fileuplod/setflag");?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="tagname" class="tagname" id="tagname" placeholder="Flag Name"> <br/>
    <input type="file" name="file_name" class="flagimg" id="flagimg">
    <input type="submit" name="flagsubmit"  value="set">
</form>
```